# View blocking off other view during translate animation

Tags: java, android, view, android-linearlayout, translate-animation

I have a view at the bottom of the screen (`LinearLayout login`), red in the picture. I want to set this view visibility to gone, and then bring in the green view ( `LinearLayout sign_in_box`) from off the screen to the middle of the screen using a `TranslateAnimation`. To do so I use this code:

```
final LinearLayout sign_in_box = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.sign_up_box);
LinearLayout login = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.start_box);
login.setVisibility(View.GONE);
sign_up_anim = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,height * 75/100,0);
sign_up_anim.setDuration(800);
sign_up_anim.setFillAfter(true);
sign_in_box.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
sign_in_box.startAnimation(sign_up_anim);
```

The problem is that the red view disappears, however the green view does not show up onto the screen until it passes where the red view is supposed to end (point A). So my animation does nothing for the first few seconds, then the view slides in from behind point A. It is acting as if the red view is blocking the green view from appearing, even though its visibility is set to gone.

[image]

Comment: Did you try placing the view after the login node in the xml? this might solve the issue since then it would be drawn above

Comment: the problem is the view is supposed to be in the same location where it is on screen (way above the login view) and the login view is attached to the bottom of the screen so I'm not sure how flipping them around would still allow me to maintain the same positions on screen